# Long tap mark notification as read on iPadOS

Tags: bug, global-inbox, ipad

I'm not sure that this behavior is intentional, but on iPadOS Chrome long tap on unread item make it read:

> [image]

Unable to reproduce on Android Chrome.

Comment: Looks like something in the OS making SE think it's one tap i.e. clicking the link but then it should also navigate there. Odd, for sure. :/

Comment: This is actually really useful. But yeah, long tap does something different on iOS. For example you can also long tap on tags to show the popup.

Comment: @Laurel with tags it's expected as long tap should mimic tooltip, i.e. the action that happens when you mouse over something, and having no mouse. But the inbox items surely don't get mark as read by just hovering over them, so there's a bug.